# Simulate a mouse-click in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Looking for a Javascript that do a left-mouse click on a image/button identified by ID or CLASS name, wait x seconds and repeat. And able to run in developer tools Console tap, in chrome and firefox.

Tried to write it myself, cause i figured it would be a simple code, but after 2 hours of trial and error with no luck, i am starting to run out of options.

Hopefully a Javascript pro out there got time to help out a very novice user ;)

Thanks

Comment: Why not buy Ranorex or Quick test pro

Comment: Not a novice question at all!

Comment: Maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use jQuery, you can use this simple function to do it:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $("#divToClick").trigger("click");
}, 1000);
```

That will call it every 1000 milliseconds, or 1 second

For a pure Javascript solution, you should take a look at [How to trigger event in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript?lq=1,)

or, if you're not interested in supporting IE, you can do it the simple way, with an `Event()` constructor, and `event.dispatch()`

Comment: .trigger saves my life.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
document.getElementById(id).click()
```

Comment: That only works for input elements and links

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/c7ghL/

Answer (score 2):

You'd use the [event constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) and `dispatchEvent` for that :

```
var support = true; // check if event constructor is supported

try {
    if (new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: false}).bubbles !== false) {
        support = false;
    } else if (new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}).bubbles !== true) {
        support = false;
    }
} catch (e) {
    support = false;
}

setInterval(function() {
    if (support) {
        var event = new MouseEvent('click');
    }else{
        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    }
    elem.dispatchEvent(event);
},1000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hLnTy/3/)

Comment: Tried the Javascript code you wrote on Fiddle, but does not click the image and returns no error.  just output 44 and clicked.

Comment: Did of course replace test with actual ID.

Comment: @zyl1647 - That's what the console does when the same value is logged over and over, it just adds a number at the front for the number of times it was logged to the console, try this and see -> http://jsfiddle.net/hLnTy/4/

Comment: Sadly the same, does however output [18, 18, 4, 3, 200, Array[3], "DBBBACCDECCD"] when i manually click the image while script runs

Comment: @zyl1647 - does the fiddle posted above actually output that, and in what browser

Comment: @zyl1647 - I've just tested this in IE9 (It won't work without attachEvent in older versions), Chrome, Firefox and Opera, and it works everywhere ?

Comment: Does output that yeh, and in Chrome.

Comment: @zyl1647 - It works just fine here? What does this do -> http://jsfiddle.net/hLnTy/5/

Comment: v5 on Fiddle outputs "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null" tried to test with http://www.brainbashers.com/10seconds.asp. v4 on said 10seconds site still dont click the image, however it does return next clicked x in line whenever i click the image manually.