# JavaScript simulate physical click on a link to bypass pop blocker(Not Jquery)

Tags: javascript

I am opening a popup after main window load.

**Problem:**

When user actually click on link the popup opens without complaining anything.
But when I am using Javascript call to click on href, I am getting popup blocker.

I am suspecting that, browser identifies that, popup is opening without any actual operation by user and that's why it is blocking popup.

In herf, I am calling a javascript method to open the popup. 
I searched all the questions regarding opening popup and simulating the click   [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20602365/1434611), these works fine to simulate the click but still getting popup blocker.
Is there any workaround to fool browser?

Comment: possibly u may try [jquery popups](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), some more [links](http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/)

Comment: It's quite irritating that, if user clicks on the link. there is no issue but it is not allowing script to open popup, while I am in same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fool the browser per-se in this scenario. You could however, launch a div as an overlay on the main window if that's an option.